# How do you prepare for crossing Borneo from coast to coast on foot?

Tags: hiking, trekking, borneo

It is on my to-do list. I know a huge and growing part is about palm oil trees. I would like to know the challenges to be aware of when crossing through the jungle, and how to prepare oneself for such a trip.

Comment: You have 3 countries to deal with, so a big question is where from and where to? Tuaran to Sandakan would qualify as "coast to coast" and there's what looks like a nice road between them.

Comment: binge watch bear grylls on netflix.

Answer (score 3):

I would start by reading [Redmond O'Hanlon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Redmond_O%27Hanlon)'s *[Into the Heart of Borneo](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/118585.Into_the_Heart_of_Borneo)* (aka *Borneo and the Poet* in some markets), which will both offer a practical and often visceral overview of the "challenges" involved, plus hopefully demonstrate that such a crossing is near-suicidal for someone unfamiliar enough to ask about it on random websites.